# vim - don't save backups if in svn working copy?

Tags: vim

I like that vim automatically saves backup files, but it is annoying when I use vim to edit a file that is in a svn working copy, since the files are already "backed up", and it creates clutter.

How do I configure vim to only save backups when I am editing a file that is NOT in a svn working copy?

Comment: Ken Liu **1,337** ●2●12 *Sweet!*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not an answer to your specific question, but I believe a better solution. Why not backup all your files into a separate directory, regardless of whether they are in source control?

Here's how, from my .vimrc. This creates the backups in the common ~/.vim_backups directory:

```
" Use a common directory for backups and swp files
" Create it if it doesn't exist
silent execute '!mkdir -p ~/.vim_backups'
set backupdir=~/.vim_backups//
set directory=~/.vim_backups//
```

Comment: not a bad idea...I just do that if I don't get any better suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

See backupdir option in vim (type :help backupdir) to create backup files in different location. You can put the definition of "backupdir" to your ~/.bashrc.

One additional point - you may still want backup files even if the file is controlled by svn, since backup will contain your local changes (not checked ones)

Comment: It's not worth it...I commit frequently enough so that this almost is never needed.